# Can I use MS SQL?

Tags: 7, database

I don't want the whole of Drupal (Drupal itself plus SQL) on the same server. I need Drupal on a normal LAMP setup connecting to a db hosted on a separate server using MS SQL. Is it possible?

I've seen there's a MS PHP drive for Drupal to work, but the drive is a Windows executable file, so I guess it won't work on a Linux box.

Alternatively, is there any difference in Drupal itself for it to be able to connect to MS SQL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Out of the box there is practically no support for MSSQL. Drupal 7 there was an attempt to support it driven by the Commerce Guys, but that work migrated to a contrib module and is not in core. Here is a quick rundown of compatibility.

**Drupal 6**: Not possible

**Drupal 7**: Possibly with the MSSQL Layer module called [SQLsrv](https://www.drupal.org/project/sqlsrv). But be prepared for issues when using contrib modules, some will not work because many modules write out SQL commands and run them with [db_query](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7) instead of the abstraction layer for performance reasons - especially complex queries.

**Drupal 8**: Not possible out of the box. There is a third party [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/sqlsrv) that provides a driver for MSSQL.

If you really want to get the most out of Drupal with as little headache as possible, run MySQL or even MarianDB on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal 7 and 8 have full MSSQL Support.

Currently, PHP7 is also supported and Linux Support for PHP7 is comming soon.

My recommendation is that - if you are using MSSQL - go for a full MS software stack.

To install Drupal on SQL Server see this tutorial:

http://www.drupalonwindows.com/en/blog/installing-drupal-windows-and-sql-server
http://www.drupalonwindows.com/en/blog/installing-drupal-8-windows

Comment: I have given up. At the time I was trying to run Drupal on Azure, which I did with some success but the problems it generated was not worth the trouble, at the end I migrated to Acquia, which is where I'm at the moment.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Unfortunately you are comparing apples to oranges. Acquia is designed to do the hosting/infrastructure work for you (and that comes at a price) and is Drupal specialized. I know projects that saved a 5 figure number per month by moving away from Acquia.

Comment: I have been running Drupal 8.4 with sqlsrv 8.x-1.0-rc4 successfully for a few months. I have had to patch core and the sqlsrv module. Core needs to be patched to allow entities to be edited, while the sqlsrv patch fixes a paging when viewing lists of entities. (https://www.drupal.org/project/sqlsrv/issues/2931061) (https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2342699)

Answer (score 1):

By default Drupal supports MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite. But you can try to extend existing classes and write your own for MsSQL (or find some existing). I don't think that MsSQL can work on Linux, but maybe via emulator.